# How do I rename values of a variable in R?

Tags: r

So I have a variable called "Answer," and the possible outputs are "y" "n" and "m" but I want to rename them "Yes" "No" and "Maybe" (respectively). I've been trying this forever and I can't get it.

Here is what my code looks like:

```
question_data %>%
  group_by(Answer) %>%
  summarise(
  Yes = "y",
  No = "n",
  Maybe = "m"
)
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong/what I should do instead? I'm using tidyverse, idk if that helps at all. Thank you for any help, I'm frustrated to tears.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If it is only recoding or change the values of a column, we use `mutate` and there is no need for `group_by` or `summarise` (summarise returns the summarised output in a single row (if it is grouped, then one row per group - in most cases)

```
library(dplyr)
question_data <- question_data %>%
    mutate(Answer = recode(Answer, y = 'Yes', n = 'No', m =  'Maybe' ))
```

-output

```
question_data
#  Answer
#1    Yes
#2     No
#3  Maybe
#4     No
#5    Yes
#6  Maybe
```

---

In `base R`, we can use `factor` with `levels` and `labels` specified in the same order

```
with(question_data, factor(Answer, 
    levels = c('y', 'n', 'm'), labels = c("Yes", "No", "Maybe")))
```

Or with a named vector to match and replace

```
setNames(c('Yes', 'No', 'Maybe'), c('y', 'n', 'm'))[question_data$Answer]
```

#### data

```
question_data <- data.frame(Answer = c('y', 'n', 'm', 'n', 'y', 'm'))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `question_data$Answer[question_data$Answer=="y"] <- "Yes"` and similar for other values that need to be replaced.